# Get Column Headers in KDB/q Query

Tags: python, kdb, q-lang

How can i get the just the column headers of a table in KDB? Is there a special query for this? I am asking because when I pull the data from the table into python the column headers are lost. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try 'cols' command.  ex:  cols tbl

Comment: Which interface you're using to get kdb+ table to python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using one of the two regular python APIs for getting data from KDB, I think both implement a Flip class from which you can get the column names (usually there is an `x` which is an array of strings).

Otherwise `cols tableName` gives you list of symbols (which would be deserialized as an array of strings in python)